# how can i stop node-cron schedule in 'while-loop'

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron, node-schedule

I want to get response for a specific url using node-cron.

As in the example code below, 'scheduler' requests to specific url every 10 seconds.

However, I want this action to be performed only 10 times.

(There may be other ways, but I definitely want to use the 'start' and 'stop' methods of node-crone.)

I really want to use the while statement.. The code I wrote doesn't wait for the response of the 'start' method, and as a result, an infinite loop is executed.

I'll leave the code I wrote below, so if you have a solution, please reply. thanks!!

```
import cron from 'node-cron';
import axios from 'axios';
import fsPromise from 'fs/promises';

let cronCnt = 0;
const cronSchedule = cron.schedule(
  '*/10 * * * * *,',
  async () => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.get(options);
      await fsPromise.writeFile(path, result.data, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
      cronCnt += 1;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  },
  {
    scheduled: false,
  },
);

(async () => {
  while (true) {
    if (cronCnt < 10) {
      await cronSchedule.start(); // i know.. 'cron.start()' doesnt'return promise... :(
    } else {
      await cronSchedule.stop(); // i know.. 'cron.stop()' doesnt'return promise... :(
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: I'd assign the `true`  in the while loop to a variable like `let isJobRunnin = true` then in your `else` statement, add `isJobRunnin = false` just above `await cronSchedule.stop();`

Comment: @SebastianGbudje 

 I left out 'break' in the example code. I've edited..
But... even as you said, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Try `while(cronCnt < 10)` then use the break at the end there. That way if cronCnt is not less than 10, then your loop should break. You wouldn't need the `if` statement. So inside the `while` loop you just add the  `await cronSchedule.start()` then outside you just do `await cronSchedule.stop();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1. Scheduling `*/10 * * * * *,` results in an exception. You'll simply need to remove that last comma.
2. Take a look at the node-cron code [here in GitHub](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/blob/ecb1e0d5d87113c03abb7d4abec29a2c3ca47e62/src/scheduler.js#L13). More on this below.

When calling `start()` in a loop, you are essentially scheduling work to be done, then clearing that work to be scheduled in the next call, as the first line in `start()` clears any previous timers.

So, let's let `node-cron` do the scheduling :

```
(() => {
  cronSchedule.start()

  while (true) {
    if (cronCnt < 10) {
      // i would sleep here for a second or something
    } else {
      cronSchedule.stop();
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, but crontCnt doesn't go up from 0, so it's an infinite loop

Comment: Add the sleep and wait it out, it'll take 110 seconds according to your schedule.

Comment: Missed something! Theres an error with your cron syntax as well, updated the answer.

Comment: `await sleepForMilliSeconds(2000);` Add sleep code in, it worked as I wanted. Your answer was helpful.